# Different validation rules for input based on another input value from FormRequest rules() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Is it possible to validate an input field conditionally based on the value of another input?

For example, there is an input `type` which can have the values `letters` or `numbers` and then there is another field which contains the `value` input.

I want that the `value` input validation rule will be `alpha` if type is `letters` and `numeric` if type is `numbers`

I am already using the pipe type of validation in the `rules` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "type" => 'required',
        "value" => 'required|min:1|max:255',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Rule::when($condition, $rules)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38450).

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'type' => ['required'],
        'value' => [
            'required',
            'min:1',
            'max:255',
            Rule::when($this->type === 'letters', ['alpha']),
            Rule::when($this->type === 'numbers', ['numeric']),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [Complex Conditional Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation), it's the solution to your request. An example is already given in the documentation however your code block will look like below.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'type' => 'required',
]);

$validator->sometimes('value', 'required|min:1|max:255|numeric', function ($input) {
    return $input->type == 'numbers';
});

$validator->sometimes('value', 'required|min:1|max:255|alpha', function ($input) {
    return $input->type == 'letters';
});
```